# How to run Kotlin Koans in IntelliJ? What is the "Main class"?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have downloaded Kotlin Koans from Github, installed IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 and opened the Koans project. As I understand I need a `Configuration` to run the examples. This `Configuration` needs a `Main class`. I cannot figure out where I find the main class in the Kotlin Koans. I have searched for one but found none (except for a special one in `htmlDemo.kt`).

I see that some kind of unit test framework is used. It probably somehow calls `task0` but the IDE shows no references to `task0` except one from `todoTask0`. The only reference to `todoTask0` is in `task0`. So we have circular references but nowhere do I find an external reference to call up one of these functions.

Can someone explain to me how to get the Kotlin Koans running in the IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: What I tried was first to open a project by specifying the directory of the Kotlin Koans. I expected a kind of project file to be found there. And indeed IntelliJ opened something and displayed a directory structure. But no way to execute something.

Then I tried to create a new Kotlin project in the directory. This allowed me to specify the JRE and the libs used. Seemed logical but still no way to execute something.

Then I tried to add a configuration. Tried Kotlin or JUnit. But don't know the main class (Kotlin) or get "JUnit not found in module 'KotlinKoans'".

Comment: Ok, I gave up on this try. Could not figure out how to create a runnable project with the Kotlin Koans. Instead, I installed the educational IDEA plugin for Kotlin (https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/03/kotlin-educational-plugin) and am using that.

Comment: For the icons to appear you need to make sure Gradle is configured in IDEA.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to install the Kotlin Edu plugin. You may read [this JB blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/03/kotlin-educational-plugin/) for additional info.

You could also run all koans tests without the plugin.IDEA allows you to run applications and tests directly from the IDE by clicking the Run icon near the test or application definition:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any Run icons.

Comment: Are you sure that you've opened the test file (`_00_Start.kt`)? What happens when you press Ctrl+Shift+F10 or Alt+Enter, while the cursor placed over `testOk` method?

Comment: Yes. When pressing Ctrl+Shift+F10 nothing happens. With Alt+Enter I get a popup menu with 2 selections: "Move to companion object" and "Convert member to extension".

Comment: Try to create new JUnit configuration and set `i_introduction._0_Hello_World._00_Start` in the `Class` field

Comment: Also, clicking on the `_00_Start` file on the Project panel with right mouse button, do you see anything related to `Run` or `Debug`?

Comment: If I try to create a new JUnit configuration and set the `Class` field I get an error message `JUnit not found in module KotlinKoans`. The right click on the file in the project panel brings up neither `Run` nor `Debug` in the popup menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116206/discussion-between-soon-and-tina-hildebrandt).

Answer (score 4):

already quite old question but I also struggled a bit. The way to do it is how they described it in their github repo (maybe they changed that since last time you checked)

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-koans

> How to build and run tests
>
> Working with the project using Intellij IDEA or Android Studio:
>
> Import the project as Gradle project. To build the project and run
>   tests use 'test' task on Gradle panel.

What I did:

1. Clone from github via File -> new project from version control -> github
2. After that was done I also could not run anything
3. File -> New Project from existing soure -> Choose your folder
4. Import Project from external model -> choose Gradle
5. No need to change anything, after that it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Follow [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html):

> 2. Open up the project in IntelliJ IDEA or your favorite editor. Note: If
>      IntelliJ IDEA prompts you to update the Kotlin library, just click
>      yes.
> 3. Run a test. Make it pass

You can trigger a test run by opening a file (i.e `kotlin-koans/test/i_introduction/_0_Hello_World/_00_Start.kt`) and hitting:
[image]

You can find more information about [running tests in IntelliJ in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html).

Comment: These symbols on the left are not displayed in my version of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I have looked into your documentation link. I find "In the Configuration tab, specify the class that contains the main() method, VM options, program arguments, working directory and other configuration-specific settings." The problem is that I can not figure out which class contains the main() method. That stops me from making any progress!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the `zsh`'s bug, can be solved in following:

1. add `setopt no_nomatch` in the end of file  `~/.zshrc`;
2. then run `source /.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

You can run them by clicking the **Check Task** button. :)

[image]